# Angular IO Pipes Impure on Cordova do not work

Tags: angular, cordova, pipe

A have an aplication made in Angular 4 and i had an AOT Compilation that works perfect in cordova browser , but when i build this application for android device there are some options that do not work , like " impure pipes " 
@Pipe({ name: 't', pure: false})

Can anyone have an idea of what is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Hi, could you add a bit more information to this issue. Like what is not working? Any error messages?

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was that i was using and sync call with JQuery $.ajax and this makes to not recover de json file that is supose to refresh in the pipe. The console gives a warning of that, not an error , so i make the mistake of ignore this warning. Ajax calls must be async on cordova